# COUNT in CASE - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to do a value assignment with a COUNT() as the when clause?

Like so:

```
SELECT @value = 
CASE 
 WHEN 
  COUNT(tableID) 
  FROM (SELECT TOP (5) tableID FROM table) AS id = 20 
 THEN 'Looks Good'
END
```

I basically what to select a variable amount of rows `[TOP (@rowCount)]`, then take action based on the number of rows counted. I'm sure I can do this someway somehow, guessing I'm just missing something in the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for code branching, the following would work:

```
IF 20 = (select count(*)
          from (select top (5) tableID from table) as id)
    PRINT 'Looks Good'
ELSE
    PRINT '5 will never equal 20'
```

If you want to get or set a value, one of the following would work:

```
SELECT case count(*)
         when 20 then 'good'
         else 'bad'
       end
 from (select top (5) tableID from table) as id
```

or

```
SELECT case
         when count(*) > 5 then 'Over 5'
         when count(*) < 5 then 'Under 5'
         else 'Exactly 5'
       end
 from (select top (5) tableID from table) as id
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question, but maybe try something like

```
select @val = case when the_number  >= 20 then 'Looks good' end
from (
  select count(*) the_number from some_table 
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using at least sql2005 or greater then this will work -

```
--create a table to test with
create table #TestTable
(
    TestTableID int primary key
)

--populate test table
declare @i int = 0;
while @i < 10
begin
    insert into #TestTable select @i;
    set @i = @i + 1;
end
GO

--now create variables to hold the TOP value and to store the result
declare @a int = 5
        ,@value varchar(10);

--correct case stmt syntax
set @value = case 
                when (select count(RecordList) as 'RecordListCount' from (select top (@a) TestTableID as 'RecordList' from #TestTable) as sq) = 20 then 'Looks Good'
            else 'Looks Bad'
        end;
select @value;
```

Remember to put the TOP variable in parentheses and to supply aliases for all of the tables and columns.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood your question. You want to know if it is possible to have TOP N rows of table, when N is variable.
If I am right,  you will need to specify a column which the table would be ordered.

Then you can use something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) TOPCOL
    FROM TABLE_NAME
) A
WHERE TOPCOL <= N
```

If I am not right, you should edit your question, because it is very hard to understand what you meant